# Post titles below the post format content

Tags: content, post-formats

I've been trying to figure out this problem for a while now:

```
<article class="post">

    <div class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </div>  <!-- end entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>  <!-- end entry-content -->
</article>
```

This display the title, then the image (audio, video, gallery embed, etc.), then the post info. I am trying to get the Image, then the Title, and then the post info.

I made this picture for what I explained.

[image]

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that way to solve my problem. Just get post format then get the content by using `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'variable_name', true);`

Example:

```
<article class="post post-<?php echo $postformat; ?>">

    <?php 

        if( $postformat == "video" ){

            $embed_video_code = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_embed_code', true);

            if ($embed_video_code) {

                echo '<div class="ajax-video-wrapper">';
                echo '<div class="ajax-video-container">';
                    echo $embed_video_code;
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';

            }

        } 
    ?>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

So to move the title below the content just move the html.

```
<article>    
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>  <!-- end entry-content -->

    <div class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </div>
</article>
```

You need to rotate your html a bit. First thing you need to do is add the wordpress function `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails')` to your functions.php. This will allow you to add featured images to each post/page.

Next in your functions.php you need to add the wordpress function `add_image_size('postimgsize', width, height, true)`. The last perimeter allows the image to be cropped from the center out to the specified and width you'd like.

Last you need to adjust your theme file.

```
<article class="post">
    <?php if(has_postthumbnail()) : ?>
         <div class="entry-postthumbnail">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail('postimgsize');?>
         </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </div>  <!-- end entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>  <!-- end entry-content -->
</article>
```

`the_post_thumbnail()` function calls the featured image and by specifying the name of the add_image_size function inside of the circle brackets, the image will crop to the exact size you would like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to display title below the content not cropping featured image :D

Comment: Sorry I was confused because you said "I am trying to get the Image, then the Title, and then the post info." So I assumed you wanted to know how to crop the image and order the html considering it was already title then post info. I edited my answer. hope that helps

Comment: Please don"t add code in bold, use backticks or code block